# Django 1.11 get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 1.11 and I'm having a issue with path parameters.
I'm getting an error like this for all requests involving path parameters.

```
Error:
TypeError at /posts/2
get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

urls.py
...
url(r'^posts',PostView.as_view()),
url(r'^posts/<int:pk>/',PostView.as_view()),
...

views.py
..
#-------- API for CRUD -----------------#
class PostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self,pk,user_id):
        try:
            return Post.objects.get(pk=pk,user_id=user_id)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self,request,pk):
        post = Post.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response({"success":True,"data":serializer.data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        post = self.get_object(pk,request.user.id)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=request.user.id)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def post(self,request):
        params = request.data
        params['user'] = request.user.id
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        saved_data = self.perform_create(serializer)
        post = PostSerializer(saved_data)
        return Response({"success":True, "message":"Post  Added Successfully","data":post.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save()
...
```

url example :

```
GET : localhost:8000/posts/2
```

Can someone tell me how to pass positional parameters.

Comment: Your `get` method should be `def get(self, request, pk)`.

Comment: It is, I just updated forgot to put the updated code here, still now working, I suspect something with the regex

Comment: did you miss a / at the end of your request posts/2 ?

Comment: @Paras: is it now complaining about the `POST`?

Comment: tried with '/' or without '/' at the end, not working in both

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No the POST method is working from the start, I'm having issues with positional params

Answer (score 1):

Your `get` and `post` signatures only accept a `self` and `request` parameter, whereas these here should include the `pk` parameter of your URL. Since you defined the same view for a URL *without* the `pk` parameter, you should make these parameters *optional* (so add a default value, in case these are missing). Like:

```
class PostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self,pk,user_id):
        # ...
        pass

    def get(self,request, pk=None):
        # ...
        pass

    def put(self, request, pk=None):
        # ...
        pass

    def post(self,request, pk=None):
        # ...
        pass
```

An alternative is to provide `kwargs` in the URL with the missing parameter, like:

```
path(r'posts',PostView.as_view(), kwargs={'pk': None}),
path(r'posts/<int:pk>/',PostView.as_view())
```

or for pre-[django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) installations, you need to define this as a regex:

```
url(r'^posts/$',PostView.as_view(), kwargs={'pk': None}),
url(r'^posts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/',PostView.as_view())
```

Comment: but I need to pass a pk to put and get calls

Comment: @Paras: you do that. But note that your *first* URL has no `pk`, and still invokes the *same* view, so without a `pk`. Now since your `get` and `put` arguments need such `pk`, we will need to pass another value to it. Perhaps the two URL modeling might be the *real* problem. It might be better to construct two views.

Comment: tried that, aint working, only the post method is working not the put and get methods

Comment: @Paras: that makes, sense, since if you reverse the URL, it will pick the first one, hence the URL is lost, you should give your views different names, and make sure that the *second* URL is triggered, with the `<int:pk>` part.

Comment: @Paras: hold on, you mix `url(..)` syntax with `path(..)` syntax.

Comment: yes, path is not available in 1.11, so how do I achieve GET POST and PUT using CBV?

Comment: @Paras: make two views, one with a `pk`, one without. As for `url(..)`, you need to write it in a regex-like syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In above code you are using `user_id`, `pk` as positional arguments in request methods and view method `get_object`. `pk` and `user_id` is available across the view. you can use them like `self.kwargs.get('pk')`, `self.request.user.pk`.
Please check the code below for implementation details.

```
class PostView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        user_id = self.request.id
        try:
           return Post.objects.get(pk=pk,user_id=user_id)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
           raise Http404

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        pass

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        pass

    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        pass
```

Comment: when I'm printing this print(self.kwargs.get('pk')) , I'm getting None

Comment: @Paras change `url(r'^posts/<int:pk>/',PostView.as_view()),` to `url(r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/',PostView.as_view()),`. Now, try printing `print(self.kwargs)` you will receive `pk` in `self.kwargs`.

Comment: it did work but only after I removed this pattern url(r'^posts',PostView.as_view()), but I now get 404 for POST call, how do I handle that? Aren't CBV suppossed to provide encapsulation for HTTP Verbs?

Comment: Anyway it did worked when I reveresed the order of both urls, meaning now they look like this :
url(r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/',PostView.as_view()),
url(r'^posts',PostView.as_view()),